# Probability. Find the CDF of $Y = X^2 $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have the uniform distribution $U(−1, 3)$. Find the CDF of $Y = X^2$. 
I thought this would be simply  $$G(y)= \int_{-\sqrt{(y)}}^{\sqrt{(y)}} \frac{1}{4}  dx$$ where $0\leq{y}<9$. Which is $G(y) = \frac{\sqrt{(y)}}{2}$.

However, the answer says when $0\leq{y}<1$ , $G(y) = \frac{\sqrt{(y)}}{2}$

And when $1\leq{y}<9$, $G(y) = \int_{-1}^{\sqrt{(y)}} \frac{1}{4} dx$ =
$\frac{\sqrt{(y)}+1}{4}$.

And $G(y)$ is the piecewise function of the 2 cases combined. My question is, why are the cases considered separately?

Comment: Because $x\mapsto x^2$ is not a bijective map between $[-1,3]$ and $[1,9]$. $X^2$ can be seen as the square of a random variable whose density is $\frac{1}{2}$ over $[0,1]$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ over $[1,3]$. Now $x\mapsto x^2$ *is* bijective between $[0,3]$ and $[0,9]$.

Comment: E.g. what do you get for $G(3)$ using your version? And what went wrong? How to avoid that?

Comment: More importantly, as a reality check, does $G(9)=1$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simply because you need to ensure the bounds of the integral also remain within the support of the random variable $X$.  Because the pdf of $X$ is only $\tfrac 1 4$ there, and zero outside of $[-1;3]$.

$\displaystyle G(y)= \int\limits_{\max(-1,-\surd y)}^{\min(3,\surd y)} \tfrac{1}{4}\,\mathrm dx$

so when $0\leq y< 1$ we have $\max(-1,-\surd y)=-\surd y$; and when $1\leq y$ it is $-1$.   Similarly the upper limit is $\surd y$ when $y< 3^2$ and $3$ otherwise.

Hence $G(y) ~=~ \begin{cases} 0 & : y<0\\[1ex] \int_{-\surd y}^{\surd y} \tfrac{1}{4}\,\mathrm dx & : 0\leq y< 1\\[1ex] \int_{-1}^{\surd y} \tfrac{1}{4}\,\mathrm dx & : 1\leq y< 9 \\[1ex] 1 & : y\geq 9\end{cases} ~=~ \begin{cases} 0 & : y<0\\[1ex] \tfrac 1 2 \surd y & : 0\leq y< 1\\[1ex] \tfrac 1 4(1+\surd y) & : 1\leq y< 9 \\[1ex] 1 & : y\geq 9\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply. Would a very similar scenario occur for, A random variable $X$ has a pdf given by $f(x) = \frac{2}{25} (x+2)$, $-2<x<3$ and letting $Y=X^2$. The CDF of Y in this case would also need such bounding and considering with separate cases, right?

Comment: The cases would be 0 <= y < 4 and 4 <= y < 9, right?

Comment: @Mathews.  Yes, that is okay.