# How to show that the cdf of Y is $F(\sqrt{Y})$ if cdf of $X$ is $F(x)$, and $Y=X^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, distribution-theory

I was trying to work through how to find the CDF of $Y$ if we know CDF of $X$ is $F_X(x)$, and $Y=X^2$.

So if I plug in $y=x^2$ then I can intuitively get

$$F_Y(y)=+\sqrt y$$

I solved this simply by solving $Y=X^2$ for $X$ and get $X=\sqrt Y$.  Is it true in general that I can just solve the relationship between to Random Variables to get the cdf of one from the other?

Related: [Probability. Find the CDF of $Y = X^2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771136/probability-find-the-cdf-of-y-x2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}[Y < y] = \mathbb{P}[X^2<y] = \mathbb{P}[|X| < \sqrt{y}] = F_X(\sqrt{y}) - F_X(-\sqrt{y})
$$
Assuming $X \ge 0$, you have $F_X(-\sqrt{y}) = 0$...

Comment: Thanks.  Now I am wondering  - if we know a relationship between $X$ and $Y$ like that, when is it *not* possible to merely solve the equation for $X$ in terms of $Y$ and substitute into $F_X(x)$?  Or is that always possible?

Comment: @nundo what if the function is not 1-1? or does not have an easy inverse...

Comment: I see so we are relying on the fact that there is an inverse function  in order to make these statements.